# Can an android phone be ported to a qemu vm?

Tags: android, linux, qemu

Im curious to know if one can clone a physical android phone and turn it into a qemu vm ?

Not simulating the entire hardware, but rather just the storage, processes, memory and so on

Comment: The Android Emulator is already a QEMU based system running on x64 or ARM64 depending on host OS. It may help to read [Why are there not generic phone OS installers?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63630/3573), [Why Android devices are more brickable than PCs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205072/3573)

Comment: I mean dd my phone storage with all apps and files and running it in android emulator

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) as StackOverflow is for specific programming problems. But realize that the flash storage on [Android devices are encrypted](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/216655/90202) so you'll have to get around that first.